# Bottom Corners Rounded?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I am currently having trouble with one section of my layout.

My layout container is white with rounded corners and a drop shadow (which is working just fine).

The thing is, I have a footer section inside the container div that is a light grey. I was hoping that the bottom corners of this div would be rounded with the container, but they are square and overlap the rounded corners of the container div.

Is there any way I can round the bottom corners of the footer div?

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 940px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90; /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
  *zoom: 1;
}

.site-footer{
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="containter">
   Test Text...
   <div class="site-footer">
      Footer text...
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue can be viewed at my website [here](http://www.noellesnotes.com/tester).

Comment: I removed the link to your website, because the container styles you mentioned aren't on that page.

Comment: Include the HTML that is causing the problem.  You are also using Bootstrap, which has implications for how to solve this problem.

Comment: FakeRainBrigand: Sorry, I forgot to add the /tester/ to the end. I'm designing it in a test directory. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `.container` styling.

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
    ....
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9gMSm/1/)**

Comment: @Noelle, you may need to have `overflow-x: hidden`.  There's a scrollbar on my screen for `.container`.  Or fix the the issue - Chrome Stable, all browser sizes.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I just modified my CSS to have overflow-x:hidden . Is the scrollbar still there for you now?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can round the bottom corners of the footer div?

**Yes.**

```
border-bottom-left-radius: /* */;
border-bottom-right-radius: /* */;
```